# Convert Float RGB Color Components to Integer in Ruby

Tags: ios, ruby, colors, cucumber

I need to convert float RGB values provided by Cucumber from an iOS app to Ints so that I can compare them as hex color to expected hex colors.

Problem is that Ruby to_s(16) only works with Fixnums, not floats.

Cucumber fetches this from iOS app:

```
{
      "red" => 0.7490196078431373,
    "alpha" => 1,
     "type" => "UIDeviceRGBColor",
     "blue" => 0,
    "green" => 0
}
```

So I have three float RGB values that I need to convert to a hexadecimal string. But I can't just say r.to_s(16). How do I convert the values properly to integers to be able to use them with string base conversion in Ruby?

Comment: hint: `0.7490196078431373 * 255 #=> 191.0`

Comment: Ok, that easy. If you make this an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source values are in the range 0..1 whereas your destination values are in the range 0..255 (or 0..0xFF for hex).

First of all, let's fetch the values:

```
data = {
      "red" => 0.7490196078431373,
    "alpha" => 1,
     "type" => "UIDeviceRGBColor",
     "blue" => 0,
    "green" => 0
}

values = data.values_at('red', 'green', 'blue')
#=> [0.7490196078431373, 0, 0]
```

Now we can multiply them by 255:

```
values.map! { |v| (v * 255).round }
#=> [191, 0, 0]
```

And finally format them as hex values:

```
'%02x%02x%02x' % values
#=> "bf0000"
```